# How to use subquery or predicate in Parse Query?

Tags: ios, sql, parse-platform

Basically, I want to make the following pseudo query for Parse. But I couldnt manage to find a feasible way to do so:

```
SELECT * FROM UserPhoto WHERE DISTANCE(UserLocation,ImageLocation) <= VisibleRadius
```

Here, distance is a function get the distance between `UserLocation` and `ImageLocation`, who are both `PFGeoPoint`. `VisibleRadius` along with `ImageLocation` are two values in the database.

In Parse, normally I will do `query.where('ImageLocation', lessThan: SomeValue)` right. But my case has two values in the database I need to consider. What should I do?

I truly appreciate any help!

Comment: So you want to select all photos that are within radius X of the users location? As in "Get me all photos that where taken within 10km around my current location"?

Comment: Only part of it. I want "Get me all photos that are taken within 10km around my current location if my current location is also within the photo's visible radius"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `currentLocation` holds the user's current location determined using `CLLocationManager`, try this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: @"<the_class_name>"];
PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
[query whereKey: @"ImageLocation" nearGeoPoint: point withinKilometers: VisibleRadius];
```

Comment: where do I get the value of VisibleRadius

Comment: Does `VisibleRadius` change for every record in the data base, or is it a constant value that you could fetch beforehand?

Comment: Each data can be different, it's basically a column . The data is set by user when they post the photo

Comment: Ok I see. I'm not sure this is supported, then. You might have to do post-processing on the client side if these values are different enough between rows...